# Use a variable defined in sub classes prototype in superclass in polymorphism

Tags: javascript, node.js

I construct a code to use polymorphism in `Node JS`.Here `item` is my super class when the `projectModule`, `testCase` and `businessComponent` are it's sub classes. In my case, every operation is the same except the file reading operation. So I used `<sub-class>.prototype.create.itemType` to create, unique, new variable withing `create()` function. When i call

```
var test = new projectModule();
test.create();
```

console log the text `create functions is called` means using `item` prototype is successful but code doesn't work correct because `itemType` is `undefined`. How can I use `itemType` variable?

```
var item = function () {};
item.prototype.create = function () {
  console.log('create functions is called');
  if(itemType==='module')
    console.log('read module json');

  if(itemType==='tc')
    console.log('read tc json');

  if(itemType==='bc')
    console.log('read bc json');
}


var projectModule = function () {};
projectModule.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
projectModule.prototype.create.itemType = 'module';


var testCase = function () {};
testCase.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
testCase.prototype.create.itemType = 'tc';


var businessComponent = function () {};
businessComponent.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
businessComponent.prototype.create.itemType = 'bc';

//call the function
var test = new projectModule();
test.create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are in need of information on how prototypical inheritance works in javascript.

What you are looking for is the keyword `this`.

Example code pulled from [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-prototype-in-plain-detailed-language/)

```
function Plant () {
​this.country = "Mexico";
​this.isOrganic = true;
}
​
​// Add the showNameAndColor method to the Plant prototype property​
Plant.prototype.showNameAndColor =  function () {
console.log("I am a " + this.name + " and my color is " + this.color);
}
​
​// Add the amIOrganic method to the Plant prototype property​
Plant.prototype.amIOrganic = function () {
​if (this.isOrganic)
console.log("I am organic, Baby!");
}
​
​function Fruit (fruitName, fruitColor) {
​this.name = fruitName;
​this.color = fruitColor;
}
​
​// Set the Fruit's prototype to Plant's constructor, thus inheriting all of Plant.prototype methods and properties.​
Fruit.prototype = new Plant ();
​
​// Creates a new object, aBanana, with the Fruit constructor​
​var aBanana = new Fruit ("Banana", "Yellow");
​
​// Here, aBanana uses the name property from the aBanana object prototype, which is Fruit.prototype:​
console.log(aBanana.name); // Banana​
​
​// Uses the showNameAndColor method from the Fruit object prototype, which is Plant.prototype. The aBanana object inherits all the properties and methods from both the Plant and Fruit functions.​
console.log(aBanana.showNameAndColor()); // I am a Banana and my color is yellow.
```